# Scraping linkedin news feed

Tags: python, web-scraping, linkedin-api

Is it possible to scrap a company's news feed on linkedin? To collect data like how many comments in each post? I wanna do it using python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api

Linkedin has a REST API which you can call on for information. You should be able to use that to get posts from a specific company.

The language you use is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. You could use [selenium with python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), which is pretty easy to use, [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) or [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) (pupeeteer with python).

Your question is too broad. Read the documentation of one of those frameworks, and try to code with it.

Comment: I tried using both scrapy and selenium but the code just can't find the divs which posts are. I wanna know if there is a way that linkedin would allow me to scrape its pages

Comment: @LuizaAmanajas you can contact them to ask them or try not to get detected. To find the content of the divs you want, you could us css selectors or xpaths: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

Comment: I tried with all find_element_by in selenium kk none of them works more than a few times. I'll have to contact them then. Not getting detected would need at least thousands of different ip addresses. Thanks

Comment: Hey, I want to build a real time ingestion system which would continuously poll the LinkedIn news feed and get data whenever posted and push to cloud. How can I achieve the same? What solution could you figure out in the end?